# find out which programs play sound python Python

Tags: python

I want to find out which programs are playing sound with a python code, I researched it a lot, even though I tried libraries like winsdk pycaw, I couldn't get any results

Comment: The question needs to be clarified.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use standard `winsound` module. Please, refer to [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/winsound.html)

If you are now under Windows, there are:

the bell character on the terminal
AppKit to play MacOS system sounds
pygame to play custom sound files
simpleaudio to play custom sound files
the beepy package

Comment: Is there a simple winsound code related to this issue?

Comment: This is not my purpose. My purpose is not to play audio, for example, to check if there is a sound from discord.exe